# Datagrid/WPF - Strange display behaviour for enumerated types

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

## Problem

When I try to display an enumerated type in a WPF data grid, the automatically assigned combobox does not appear correctly.

When the data grid is first shown 'enum' is not displayed at all, while other types like 'bool' and 'double' are displayed as expected:

[image: Before editing]

But if I click on an enum cell, I see the combobox appearing:

[image: After editing]

How to have the combobox to appear immediately?

## Definitions

In my exact situation, I just want to display a `List` of `PathSettings`.

`PathSetting` is just a bunch of data defined like that:

```
public class PathSettings
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public PathType PathType { get; set; }
    public double Gain { get; set; }
}
```

Where `PathType` is some enumerated value:

```
public enum PathType
{
    Direct,
    Amplified,
    Load
}
```

And lets say I wanna display the following list:

```
var tests = new List<PathSettings>
{
    new PathSettings { IsSelected = false, PathType = PathType.Direct, Gain = 2.0 },
    new PathSettings { IsSelected = true, PathType = PathType.Amplified, Gain = 2.5 },
    new PathSettings { IsSelected = false, PathType = PathType.Load, Gain = 0.9 },
};
```

## Coding attempt

I first created a `ViewAdapter` class to convert my `List` to some `DataView` object:

```
public class ViewAdapter
{
    private static IEnumerable<PathSettings> buildDummyEntries()
    {
        return new List<PathSettings>
        {
            new PathSettings { IsSelected = false, PathType = PathType.Direct, Gain = 2.0 },
            new PathSettings { IsSelected = true, PathType = PathType.Amplified, Gain = 2.5 },
            new PathSettings { IsSelected = false, PathType = PathType.Load, Gain = 0.9 },
        };
    }

    public ViewAdapter() : this(buildDummyEntries())
    {

    }
    public ViewAdapter(IEnumerable<PathSettings> settings)
    {
        if (settings == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }

        // 1) Transform to cell collection
        var cells = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>>();
        foreach (var s in settings)
        {
            cells.Add(new ObservableCollection<object>
            {
                s.IsSelected,
                s.PathType,
                s.Gain,                    
            });
        }

        // 2) Transform to datatable
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("IsSelected", typeof(bool));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("PathType", typeof(PathType));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Gain", typeof(double));
        foreach (var t in settings)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataTable.NewRow());
        }

        // 3) Transform to data view and feed with cells
        Settings = new DataView(dataTable);
        for (var i = 0; i < settings.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < cells[i].Count; j++)
            {
                Settings[i][j] = cells[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public DataView Settings
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

And fed the `ItemsSource` of my `DataGrid` with it:

```
<Window x:Class="EnumInDataGrid.MainWindow"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EnumInDataGrid"

    Title="MainWindow" 

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:Height="350" d:Width="525"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewAdapter, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" 
    d:DesignHeight="239" d:DesignWidth="308">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewAdapter />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}"
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
            CanUserResizeRows="False" 
            CanUserSortColumns="False" 
            SelectionMode="Single" 
            SelectionUnit="Cell"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Do you have custom grid styles?

Comment: Are you using AutoGenerateColumns?

Comment: @sll, No I haven't, almost all code is provided above and you can surround it from a simple new WPF Application project in Visual Studio to reproduce same issue.

Comment: @MBen, I don't modify the AutoGenerateColumns property, so it must keep it's default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, WPF DataGrids are in Read-Only mode and you have to click a cell to edit them. The  read-only template for a ComboBox column is a TextBlock, while the editing template is a ComboBox.

If you want to display the ComboBox right away, use a custom `DataGridTemplateColumn` containing a ComboBox.

As far as the enum value not showing up right away, I suspect it has something to do with your data source. I did a quick test and auto-generated columns containing enum values do show up correctly.

One way to determine if your data source is the problem or not, is get rid of the DataView. A DataGrid can bind to any enumerable collection, so bind it directly to your `List<PathSettings>` instead of creating the `DataView`.

I really don't know why you're using a `DataView` object in the first place. Ideally collections in WPF should be `ObservableCollection<DataObject>` and `DataObject` should be something that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This ensures that the UI gets updated automatically when your collections or properties change.

Comment: Thank you very much, binding directly to the list of PathSettings solved the issue.

Comment: The reason I used a DataView in the first place is that i'm new to WPF and I justed copy-pasted some example I saw. At the beginning I was not much interested in having UI updated from collection (while worrying on how this could be done), but this is very valuable guidance on how to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: @CitizenInsane No problem, glad that worked out :) Also if you're new to WPF, I would highly recommend looking into the MVVM design pattern. It is perfectly suited for WPF's binding system, and keeps UI separate from business logic. I wrote a quick intro to it here if you're interested: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/